# What am I missing in my code? JAVA

Tags: java, string

This is my chunk of code. I am using a for loop to iterate through a string, pull out a token (a word separated by a space), determine if it is a reserved word or not, if so it prints "Reserved word is: ", otherwise it prints "Current word is: ". This is what I've got so far, I am stuck on how to make the isKeyWord work. 
Note: I cannot use a split function, scanner or tokenizer. Just a for loop.

```
public class Week3Project {
    final static String program = "/*\n" +
" * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.\n" +
" * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates\n" +
" * and open the template in the editor.\n" +
" */\n" +
"package testapplication2;\n" +
"\n" +
"import java.util.Scanner;\n" +
"\n" +
"/**\n" +
" *\n" +
" * @author james\n" +
" */\n" +
"public class TestApplication2 {\n" +
"\n" +
"    /**\n" +
"     * @param args the command line arguments\n" +
"     */\n" +
"    public static void main(String[] args) {\n" +
"        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);\n" +
"        \n" +
"        System.out.println(\"Enter integer #1\");\n" +
"        int num1 = input.nextInt();\n" +
"        \n" +
"        System.out.println(\"Enter integer #2\");\n" +
"        int num2 = input.nextInt();\n" +
"        \n" +
"        System.out.println(\"Enter integer #3\");\n" +
"        int num3 = input.nextInt();\n" +
"        \n" +
"        System.out.println(\"Enter integer #4\");\n" +
"        int num4 = input.nextInt();\n" +
"        \n" +
"        System.out.println(\"Enter integer #5\");\n" +
"        int num5 = input.nextInt();\n" +
"        \n" +
"        //determine the sum\n" +
"        int sum = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5;\n" +
"        \n" +
"        //this is helpful to make sure your sum is correct\n" +
"        System.out.println(\"The sum is: \" + sum);\n" +
"        \n" +
"        //why doesn't this generate the sum correctly\n" +
"        double average = sum / 5;\n" +
"        \n" +
"        //The average, lets hope its right...\n" +
"        System.out.println(\"The average of your numbers is: \" + average);\n" +
"        \n" +
"    }\n" +
"    \n" +
"}\n" +
"";


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = program;

        String s = "";
        String[] keywords = {"abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break", "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const", "continue", "default", "do", "double", "else", "enum",
 "extends", "final", "finally", "float", "for", "goto", "if", "implements", "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native", "new", "package", "private", "protected", "public", "return", "short", "static",
 "strictfp", "super", "switch", "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "try", "void", "volatile", "while"};
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            s += str.charAt(i) + "";
            if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' || str.charAt(i) == '\t' || str.charAt(i) == '\n') {
                String currentWord = s.toString();
                //System.out.println(currentWord);                
                boolean isKeyWord = false; 
                for (int j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) { 
                    if (currentWord.equalsIgnoreCase(keywords[j])) { 
                        isKeyWord = true;
                    }
                } break; } }
                if (isKeyWord == true) {
                    System.out.println("Reserved word is: ["  + currentWord + "]");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Current word is: [" + currentWord + "]")
                }
                s = "";//Clear the string to get it ready to build next token.


            }
        }
```

Comment: Remove the `break`. Don't declare `isKeyWord` in the loop. Fix your indentation.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried so many methods to work this thing out, i've spent about 10 hours on it... ouch.

Comment: I think the `break;` is in the wrong place.  It should be straight after `isKeyWord = true;`, so that we don't check every keyword if we find a match.

Comment: I think you're right- I still can't get it to print the reserved words, though. It just goes straight to the else statement of printing the current word. hmm

Comment: you are adding `str.charAt(i)` to your current word string unconditionally. After that you check whether `if (str.charAt(i) == ' '...`, meaning that `s` contains one space (or tab, or line feed) character too many

Comment: The **isKeyword** flag is intended so that the inner **for** loop does not need to iterate through the entire keyword array when a match is found and therefore the **break** is to be placed directly under the `isKeyWord = true;` within the same **if** statement as I had shown you within a comment in your previous post.

Comment: Thank you for that, this is literally my first day on the site! I have done so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' || str.charAt(i) == '\t' || str.charAt(i) == '\n') {
            // end of token, check if key word
            String currentWord = s.toString();     
            boolean isKeyword = false       
            for (int j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) { 
                if (currentWord.equalsIgnoreCase(keywords[j])) { 
                    isKeyword = true;
                    break;
                } 
            }
            if(isKeyword) {
                System.out.println("Reserved word is: ["  + currentWord + "]");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Current word is: [" + currentWord + "]");
            }
            s = "";//Clear the string to get it ready to build next token.
        } else {
            // continue building token
            s += str.charAt(i) + "";
        }
    }
```

Your version of the loop appends the space/tab/newline before checking, which causes the current word to never match your key words.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you!!!! Lets be best friends :,)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would probably move the `String[]` containing `keywords` to a `static final` field (but I have not pasted it here, because it is quite long - and it doesn't ***need*** to change). Next, prefer a `StringBuilder` over all of those concatenations. And `Character.isWhitespace(char)` is a nice method for determining if you have encountered whitespace. Something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < program.length(); i++) {
    char ch = program.charAt(i);
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
        sb.append(ch);
    } else {
        String token = sb.toString();
        if (token.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        boolean isKeyWord = false;
        for (String word : keywords) {
            if (word.equals(token)) {
                isKeyWord = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("%s word is : [%s]%n", 
                isKeyWord ? "Reserved" : "Current", token);
        sb.setLength(0);
    }
}
```

And, in Java 8+, that array search *might* be done with an `Arrays.stream` and an `anyMatch` like

```
boolean isKeyWord = Arrays.stream(keywords).anyMatch(token::equals);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if this can help you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String[] keywords = {"abstract", "assert", "boolean", "break", "byte", "case", "catch", "char", "class", "const", "continue", "default", "do", "double", "else", "enum",
    "extends", "final", "finally", "float", "for", "goto", "if", "implements", "import", "instanceof", "int", "interface", "long", "native", "new", "package", "private",
    "protected", "public", "return", "short", "static",
    "strictfp", "super", "switch", "synchronized", "this", "throw", "throws", "transient", "try", "void", "volatile", "while"};

 for (String value : keywords) {
   if (program.contains(value)) {
     System.out.println("Reserved word is: [" + value + "]");
   }
 }
}
```

My Result

Reserved word is: [class] 
Reserved word is: [do]
Reserved word is: [double]
Reserved word is: [import]
Reserved word is: [int]
Reserved word is: [new]
Reserved word is: [package]
Reserved word is: [public]
Reserved word is: [static]
Reserved word is: [this]
Reserved word is: [void]

Comment: And what happens if the input string contains words like **classed**, or **don't**, or **doubles**, or **imported**, .... which are not Java Keywords? Both **don't** and **doubles** contains **do** for example.